# Setting up the Eclipse environment for Protege 4.1: compilation issues

Tags: java, eclipse, protege

I have been trying to build a Protege distribution within my eclipse environment as per the steps listed in [here](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/CompileProtege4InEclipseFromSvn#Instructions_for_Compiling_and_Running_Protege_4.1.2B_in_Eclipse_using_the_sources_from_SVN). I am using Eclipse Luna with JRE/JDK 1.8.0_45 on Windows 7.  I have successfully checked out the following workspace using TortoiseSVN:

https://smi-protege.stanford.edu/repos/protege/protege4/ide/eclipse/protege4.1/trunk

and completed all the steps up to number 3 (Load the Workspace). However, when I try to compile the project (either via the easy or the harder way - as discussed in protegewiki), I am returned with a number of compilation errors. In a nutshell, if I employ the   - Step 4b: Run Protege the Harder Way (use only if the easy way 4a did not work), the following scripts ran successfully:

- Build.Protege.Infrastructure
- Build.Common
- Build.Core
- Build.Jaxb.Lib
- Build.Owlapi.Lib

Whereas, a high number of errors on the Build.Owl.Editor, as collected in this [logfile](https://www.hightail.com/download/bXBhU2Vpd0l5UkZqQThUQw)

Furthermore, running the OWLViz script fails as follows:

```
Buildfile: D:\Protege-API\org.coode.owlviz\build.xml 
init: 
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Protege-API\org.coode.owlviz\build\lib 
checkProtegeLibs: 
     [echo] ********************************************************** 
     [echo] Using Protege Home = D:\Protege-API\Protege 
     [echo] Using Java Version = 1.8 
     [echo] ********************************************************** 
checkProtegeLibsAndReport: 
     [echo] Missing protege libraries.  You need to set 
     [echo] the PROTEGE_HOME environment variable to a 
     [echo] protege installation directory where the 
     [echo] appropriate plugins have been installed. 
     [echo] Alternatively set the jar libs in local.properties (protege.lib=...) 
     [echo] Use the -v option to ant to see what jars are missing. 

BUILD FAILED 
D:\Protege-API\org.coode.owlviz\build.xml:65: missing protege libraries
```

Where am I going wrong?  Am I missing anything rather obvious? the tools.jar for Ant is the same version as my JRE/JDK (1.8.0_45).

Thank you all for your help,

Regards,

I.

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason but it sounds like a contributing factor: "checkProtegeLibsAndReport: 
     [echo] Missing protege libraries.  You need to set 
     [echo] the PROTEGE_HOME environment variable to a "

Comment: Ignazio, thanks for your reply, much appreciated. I have also posted it to the Protege mailinglist, but I have had no responses so far. What confuses me is that the setting of PROTEGE_HOME is only introduced in the set of instructions for adding your own plugin-in (as per http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/CompileProtege4InEclipseFromSvn#Instructions_for_Compiling_and_Running_Protege_4.1.2B_in_Eclipse_using_the_sources_from_SVN). Where should PROTEGE_HOME point to? Thank you, I.

Comment: That could have been a mistake in the instructions - it seems to be needed for both. PROTEGE_HOME should point at your protege installation folder.

Comment: Thanks Ignazio, much appreciated. I have had a response from the Protege Mailing list and was asked to move to V.5 with Maven. It works fine now. Thank you again, I.

Comment: Could you please post a solution or close the question.